# Rails Migration for Changing String to Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Nested Model called 'Lines'. It goes:

User has many Manufacturers has many Lines.

And I'm nesting Lines within Manufacturers. Problem is, I was a dummy and named the manufacturer_id in the db/schema for Lines as a STRING datatype instead of an INTEGER. I can't believe it. What do I need to do to change it to an integer?  I don't know if I need to drop the table, etc? Someone please help...

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140316023038) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "lines", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "manufacturer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "lines", ["manufacturer_id"], name: "index_lines_on_manufacturer_id", using: :btree

  create_table "manufacturers", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "manufacturers", ["user_id"], name: "index_manufacturers_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "fax"
    t.string   "inside_sales_office"
    t.string   "inside_sales_cell"
    t.string   "inside_sales_email"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, if you're still in development mode and you're not sharing your schema with a team, just `rake db:rollback` until it drops the Lines table, edit the line in your migration from:

```
   t.string   "manufacturer_id"
```

to

```
   t.integer   "manufacturer_id"
```

then call `rake db:migrate`.  As elegant as the migration facility in Rails is, there's nothing that prevents you from rolling back and making changes this way.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal run:

```
rails g migration change_manufacturer_id_in_lines
```

Then in the migration file

```
class ChangeManufacturerIdInlines < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
   change_column :lines, :manufacturer_id, :integer
  end

  def down
   change_column :lines, :manufacturer_id, :string
  end
end
```

[Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column)

Comment: It's throwing a lot of errors. I have 'Lines' as a model, not as a column. Doesn't that make it its own table? Is change_table a method for migrations?

Comment: @momchenr I have updated the answer to reflect lines as the model

Comment: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "line" does not exist

Comment: @momchenr should be plural lines and not line in your migration file

Comment: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "manufacturing_id" of relation "lines" does not exist

Comment: Changed it to manufacturer_id, like it needed to be, and got: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "manufacturing_id" of relation "lines" does not exist

Comment: @momchenr as your error shows you are using `manufacturing_id` instead of `manufacturer_id` I have updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "manufacturer_id" cannot be cast to type integer

Comment: @momchenr you probably want to delete all the records with `manufacturer_id` set as a string, else Postgres would not allow you change the column type

Comment: ran Line.delete_all in console, appears I have no Lines left in DB. Same error when trying to run Migration.

Comment: @momchenr you have existing indexes on that column too, you might as well rollback those index migration